# How to setup the Tabs Navigation in a typical view in wpf/silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, navigation, tabs

How do i get the tabs to stop in the order I want across usercontrol contained elements to local elements in a view, the view is static xaml, **not** composed ( like with prism ), should this involve code, or can i do this in xaml only? also if you know how to do this in blend that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in XAML by setting `TabNavigation="Local"` or `"Cycle"` on the container if you want your tabbing to remain within this container. Then adjust the `TabOrder` and `IsTabStop` properties on child elements to define which controls will get focus and in what order.